# Volume of a solid with a circular base

Tags: integration, volume, solid-geometry, cross-sections

Find the volume of the solid with a circular base of radius 9 and the cross sections perpendicular to the y-axis are squares.

I've never solved a problem like this before. How can I go about setting up the integral for this particular problem?

Comment: Is it a transition piece? Before integrating can you describe it more and/or sketch it as much as you can?

Comment: @Narasimham That's also why I'm a bit confused. The professor has thrown this problem in an assignment the way I've written it above. I don't think it's a transition piece. I wish I could describe/sketch it more, but I'm still trying to figure out how to set up/approach the problem.

Comment: [This should give an idea of what the solid looks like](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Plot3D%5B2+HeavisideTheta%5B9%5E2-x%5E2-y%5E2%5D+Sqrt%5B%28+9%5E2-+y%5E2%29%5D%2C%7Bx%2C-10%2C10%7D%2C%7By%2C-10%2C10%7D%2C%7Bz%2C0%2C20%7D%5D).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So because of symmetry, split the solid in half along a diameter. This simplifies things.

> the cross sections perpendicular to the y-axis are squares

We can thus slice this solid into vertical squares. Have you ever chopped or seen someone chopped a vegetable like a cucumber like in the video below? It is similar to that.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EXgchTrIgw4

So the side length of each slice would be a chord of the circle parallel to the y-axis. The area of each slice would be the square of that. To find the volume of the half-solid we would simply add up the areas of the slices, which is simply integration. So we can integrate the half-solid like this:

$\int_{0}^{9} (2*\sqrt{81 - x^{2}})^2 dx$

From the Pythagorean theorem and area of a square

And then we multiply the above integral by 2.

Since this is an assignment I assume you are in a calculus class or know how to do integration for this problem. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer and explain this. I attempted to solve this before you posted your answer and I got a different answer. This is a picture of my attempt at a solution: https://imgur.com/a/FplaDlO. Since the the cross-sections are perpendicular to the y-axis, don't we have to integrate with respect to y? Please take a look at my solution and let me know what you think.

Comment: I am very sorry, I tend to make silly mistakes. Yes, your approach is correct, I edited my answer. Thank you!

Comment: Also because of symmetry I don't think it matters for x-axis vs y-axis. The base is a circle. And also the x in dx is a integration variable, not for x-axis

Comment: Could not quite follow how volume was computed. Should it not be $\int (2*\sqrt{81 - x^{2}})^2 dz?$

Comment: @Narasimham, That is the indefinite integral used. However, to find the volume you have to use the definite integral between two points in order to get a numerical answer.

Comment: An indefinite integral is the antiderivative of an equation, and is another equation. The definite integral is the area under the graph of an equation and is  a number. The two are linked by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus #2

Comment: Quite familiar with them.

Comment: @Narasimham were you talking about the dz in your integral?

Comment: Yes, that should be so in general, but am afraid being suggested towards a chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137873/discussion-between-meltedstatementrecognizing-and-narasimham).

Answer (score 2):

There are many possibilities.  Take a look at a solid carved out of a unit sphere as a particular case.

When two planes $\dfrac{z}{x}=2$ intersect a sphere radius $\sqrt 5 $ we have two red great circle intersections and all sections normal to y-axis between these intersection great circles are squares.

The squares stand over $xOy$ plane parallel with an edge on this plane being parallel to $xOz$ plane between ellipse projections as shown in a 3d hand sketch below.
Since square discs are stacked integration should proceed with resp to $y$ axis, with elemental volumes obtained by integration with $dy$.

[image]

Parameterization of the spheres radius $\sqrt 5$ centered at origin:

$$P(x,y,z)= (\pm t ,\sqrt5 \sqrt{1-t^2}, 2t ) $$

$$ y= \sqrt5 \sqrt{1-t^2} ; dy =\frac{\sqrt5 t dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2}} $$

$$     dV= 4 t^2. dy =4 t^2\frac{\sqrt5 t dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}$$
$$     V = 4 {\sqrt5 }\int _0^1\; t^3 {\sqrt{1-t^2}} dt; \; $$

Hope you can take it from here ( substitution $t^2=u$) scaling radius from $\sqrt5$ to 9 by cubing this ratio for volume multiplication and then doubling it for the $-y$ part of the solid.